# Can I use the 6 channel 5.1 usb external soundcard with guitar rig 5 software?

Tags: electric-guitar, software, guitar-effects, live-sound, computer

I have been looking for a way to use effect pedals as I am paraplegic. I do not have enough money to buy a Line-6 60 Watts amp, and I came across the Guitar Rig 5 software after reading.
However, I can't afford a Focusrite sound card. Can a 6-channel 5.1 USB external soundcard work with the software? If yes, how do I connect it to be able to play on stage?

[image]

Comment: I would advise against using an interface made by a brand that doesn't specifically make musician's gear. You will need a dedicated guitar input (which is different form a microphone or a line input) and the interface and its drivers will need to be made for low-latency operation. The cheapest that offers reasonable quality would be something like the Behringer U-Phoria UM2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the USB interface for the output ( you'll need ASIO4ALL most likely to get low-latency ) but for playing your Guitar into the PC you'll need a different interface that can accept high impedence inputs as mentioned by "Your Uncle Bob" in the comments.  A low cost option for you would be this:

[https://www.amazon.com/Guitar-Bass-Cable-Adapter-Recording/dp/B00ABRE8BY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ABRE8BY)

It lets you plug your guitar into your PC via USB.  It will show up as another interface in ASIO4ALL, or it may have actual ASIO drivers from the manufacturer, then you would set the input in Guitar Rig 4, or your DAW. If you own "Rocksmith" ( Console / PC Guitar learning game ) it actually comes with one.